# Response is undefined via ajax client but proper tru url

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I'm setting up an ajax client with a dummy server (just to test). I've managed to resolve the cors issue it seems, but the response as seen from the ajax client is undefined. When I get at the same URL using just a browser thought, it displays the object properly.

```
// server-side
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
router.use(cors());

var data = [
    {"id": 1, "message": 'first object'},
    {"id": 2, "message": 'second object'},
    {"id": 3, "message": 'third  object'}
];

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("building response body");
    res.json(data);
});


// client-side
function fetcher() {
    console.log("fetch from:" + rootUrl + arrayEndpoint);
    fetch(rootUrl + arrayEndpoint, {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            console.log("response: " + response.body);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error: " + error);
        });
}
```

The response printed to the console of the client:

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "https://angry-badger-63.localtunnel.me/getArray/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }
undefined
```

And on the browser:

```
[{"id":1,"message":"first object"},{"id":2,"message":"second object"},{"id":3,"message":"third  object"}]
```

So I'm pretty sure my server-side is fine (it does send what I expect to the browser and how complicated can resp.json(object) really be?), but apparently something about the ajax client I'm not seein. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Read the `fetch()` documentation.  `.body` doesn't exist; you want `.json()`.

Comment: You are correct. That made me realize what the real source issue was - response.json() also returns a promise which I wasn't handling, so even then the result was a pending promise. So I needed another then.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account SLak's comment, fetch doesn't have resp.body, which I sort just had assumed. Huge blind spot there.

That revealed another issue - which was that resp.json() (which would be the actual way to handle it) returns a promise, which I wasn't handling. Actually it seems the parsing of the response (whether with .json() or with .text()) returns a promise in general. I'm still not really getting the array proper, but to keep things on topic here's a corrected snippet to parse a generic json object:

```
//client.js
function fetcher() {
    console.log("fetch from:" + rootUrl + arrayEndpoint);
    fetch(rootUrl + arrayEndpoint,{
        mode: "cors",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            response.json()
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("error:" + error));
}


//server.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
/* GET users listing. */
router.use(cors());

var data = {"1":{"id":1, "message": 'first object'},
  "2":{"id":2, "message": 'second object'},
  "3":{"id":3, "message": 'third  object'}};

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("building response body")
  console.log(data)
  res.json(data);
});
```